# Crear "samples" con datos parciales

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando con una distribución normal donde 10% de los datos están por encima de una longitud0 y el 5% por debajo de una longitud1.

He estado intentando usar las funciones `sample` y `dnorm` de distintas maneras pero como no tengo los valores mínimos y máximos o la media de los mismos, las muestras no me dan mucha confianza. ¿Existe alguna forma/función que me permita generar una muestra fiable con estos datos?

Comment: Bienvenido/a, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask]. Tu pregunta es algo vaga, por empezar no me queda claro si ya tienes un conjunto de datos y deseas obtener una muestra con cierta distribución, o buscas generar un conjunto de los mismos siguiendo un criterio, por otro lado te sugiero que adjuntes el código de lo que has intentado hacer. De cualquier forma `sample` es una buena opción si determinas previamente las probabilidades que quieres para cada grupo, si tuvieras 5 longitudes armarías 5 pasos  con 10%, 5% y un 85% distribuido en las otras 3.

Comment: Como bien comentas busco generar un conjunto de estos datos siguiendo un criterio. ¿Podrías ser algo mas especifico sobre como usar sample con probabilidades? He intentado por ejemplo hacer algo similar a esto  `sample(0:2, size=100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.10,.05,.85))` pero por lo que puedo entender y me comentas necesitaria hacer distintos samples para cada espacio de la muestra y dado que no tengo delimitaciones de maximos y minimos de los datos tampoco me queda claro que podria poner en ellos.

Comment: Así como lo estás planteando `sample` va a generar 100 valores donde el resultado final se debería acercar a 10 números `0`, 5 `1` y 85 `2`. Siempre necesitas definir o un vector de casos o una secuencia de números como el espacio de trabajo de `sample`, no me queda claro eso de que no tienes limites máximos y mínimos. ¿Podrías definir una muestra de ejemplo de lo que quieres lograra?

Comment: Con mínimos y máximos me refiero al valor más pequeño de la muestra y al más grande, ejemplo:  de  la muestra valores correspondientes al 10% (menores a 5) ` 3 5 4 3 4 2 1 5 4 3` , 85% de valores situados entre 5 y 10 ` 9 8 6 7 6 ... ` , 5% de valores situados por encima de 10 `11 15 14 13 12`.

Comment: No hay forma de generar un conjunto de ejemplos sin establecer un límite a los valores, lo que puedes hacer es que ese límite sea muy grande, el problema es que si es muy grande vas a tener saltos enormes entre cada grupo, el tercer grupo en vez de tener `11 15 14 13 12` tendrías número como `468797814799 12540426804, etc`. Según tu ejemplo yo generaría 3 `samples` distintos en las cantidades que mencionas y con límites propios de cada grupo.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a responderte para no dejar "colgada" esta pregunta. El uso de [`sample()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html) para lo que buscas puede servirte siempre que entiendas que necesitas establecer los limites de cualquier muestra. En tu caso si tu universo va de 0 a 20 y buscas un 10% de casos entre 0 y 4, un 85% entre 5 y 10 y un 5% para valores mayores a 10. Puedes construir una muestra de 100 valores de la siguiente forma:

```
  muestra <- c(sample(0:4,5,replace=TRUE),
             sample(5:10,85,replace=TRUE),
             sample(11:20,10,replace=TRUE))
```

Si graficáramos la muestra:

```
plot(muestra)
smoothingSpline = smooth.spline(muestra, spar=0.8)
lines(smoothingSpline, col='red', lwd=3)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]